# Using an Iterator inside a for loop to remove elements from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have an ArrayList of objects that have a version number as a field.  I want to do some work on that ArrayList, but I only want the most recent version of the object.  I was thinking of coding as such:

```
ArrayList<ObjectVO> ObjectList = getObjectList();
for(ObjectVO myVO : ObjectList) {
  Iterator<ObjectVO> iter = ObjectList.iterator();

  while(iter.hasNext()) {
     ObjectVO checkVO = iter.next();
     if(myVO.getID().equals(checkVO.getID()) {
         //they are the same object ID.  Check the version number, remove it lower
         if(myVO.getVersion() > checkVO.getVersion()) {
              iter.remove();
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

Is this valid?  I don't know if the fact that we are in a for loop originally would break the mutability of the ArrayList at runtime.

Comment: No, this won't work. `iter.remove()` will cause the out for loop to fail with `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Could I just replace the first for loop with another Iterator, and have two iterators running in parallel?

Comment: You would have to use the iterator in the outer loop, and the enhanced for loop in the inner loop. That should work I guess.

Comment: @DorianGray no, that would also break.

Comment: @user3334871 are you trying to keep the thing with the highest version number?

Comment: @Andy Why? Inner enhanced for loop would be recreated on every outer iteration.

Comment: @DorianGray because the outer iterator wouldn't be recreated.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, that's the plan.  What if I create a temp ObjectList, have an iterator at the start for the original object list.  Then I get the first object through the iterator, and run through the tempObjectList with a for loop.  If I detect a higher version number, I call `iter.remove()`.  That would remove the object from the original list, not break mutability, and I can break out of the loop as soon as I detect a remove so I don't waste processing power

Comment: And it doesn't have to, if you call `iter.remove()` only once. You would only decide whether to remove the current element, and break the inner loop if you find a higher version.

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. `iter.remove()` will cause the out for loop to fail with `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Instead of doing this, you can do this with indexed for loops, and a `BitSet` to keep track of things you want to remove:

```
BitSet toRemove = new BitSet();
for (int m = 0; m < ObjectList.size(); ++m) {
  if (toRemove.get(m)) continue;
  ObjectVO myVO = ObjectList.get(m);

  for (int c = 0; c < ObjectList.size(); ++c) {
    if (toRemove.get(c)) continue;
    ObjectVO checkVO = ObjectList.get(c);

    if(myVO.getID().equals(checkVO.getID()) {
      //they are the same object ID.  Check the version number, remove it lower
      if(myVO.getVersion() > checkVO.getVersion()) {
          toRemove.set(c);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is basically your code, but it doesn't do the removal yet. Then you can sweep through the list after and remove them:

```
int dst = 0;
for (int src = 0; src < ObjectList.size(); ++src) {
  if (!toRemove.get(src)) {
    ObjectList.set(dst++, ObjectList.get(src));
  }
}
ObjectList.subList(dst, ObjectList.size()).clear();
```

The point of using a `BitSet` like this is that removal from an `ArrayList` is inefficient if you are removing from anywhere other than the end, because it requires all of the elements "to the right" of the element you remove to be shuffled along by one position. The loop with the set/get and clear allows you to only move each of the retained elements once.

---

You can do a bit better than the quadratic loop, though, if you group the list elements by things with the same ID: then you don't need to keep on checking the entire list:

```
BitSet toKeep = new BitSet();
IntStream.range(0, ObjectList.size())
    .mapToObj(a -> a)
    .collect(
        groupingBy(a -> ObjectList.get(a).getID(),
                   maxBy(comparingInt(a -> ObjectList.get(a).getVersion()))))
    .values()
    .forEach(a -> toKeep.set(a));

int dst = 0;
for (int src = 0; src < ObjectList.size(); ++src) {
  if (toKeep.get(src)) {
    ObjectList.set(dst++, ObjectList.get(src));
  }
}
ObjectList.subList(dst, ObjectList.size()).clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the memory, rather than do an O(N^2) operation, you could do this more efficiently (O(N)) by using a Map to track the newest Version for each Id. One pass tracks the newest version for each Id, and the second removes elements which are not the latest.

```
Map<Integer, Thing> newestById = new HashMap<>();

for (Thing thing : list) {
  newestById.merge(thing.id, thing, (a,b) -> a.version > b.version ? a : b);
}
list.removeIf(thing -> thing != newestById.get(thing.id)); }
```

Depending on your use case, you might even be able to store your data in a Map instead of a List, and check if the version is the latest before adding it to the Map.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have discussed this won't work. You have three options as I see them, trading memory for CPU cycles/flexibility. I've used Integer instead of ObjectVO in my examples, but it'll be trivial to swap them.

**Option 1** - moderate memory, single-pass of the array

Track the highest ID you've seen and populate an ArrayList with new items as they meet the criteria. When you encounter a new higher ID, throw away the ArrayList and create a new one:

```
ArrayList<Integer> objectList = getObjectList();
Integer bestId = -1;
ArrayList<Integer> allObjectsMatchingId = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer currentObject : objectList) {
    if(currentObject > bestId) {
        bestId = currentObject;
        allObjectsMatchingId = new ArrayList<>();
    } else if(currentObject == bestId) {
        allObjectsMatchingId.add(currentObject);
    }
}
return allObjectsMatchingId;
```

**Option 2** - more expensive memory, single-pass of the array, most flexible.

For each ID you see, create an ArrayList and store it against a map. This allows you to easily change the criteria about what ID you want to keep.

```
ArrayList<Integer> objectList = getObjectList();
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> objectsById = new HashMap<>();
for(Integer currentObject : objectList) {
    ArrayList<Integer> listForId = objectsById.get(currentObject);
    if(listForId == null) {
        listForId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    listForId.add(currentObject);
    objectsById.put(currentObject, listForId);
}
Integer bestId = -1;
for(Integer i : objectsById.keySet()) {
    if(i > bestId) {
        bestId = i;
    }
}
return objectsById.get(bestId);
```

**Option 3** - no additional memory aside from id, two-passes of the array.

Search through the ArrayList for the highest ID, then filter the array to only elements that pass that filter.

This is the closest to your current implementation, the difference being that you do them in separate steps. This reduces complexity from O(N^2) to O(N), and is valid as you aren't modifying the ArrayList while iterating it. You could use a Stream here to filter instead of an iterator if you're Java 8 compatible. See [Java: Efficient ArrayList filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280722/java-efficient-arraylist-filtering)

```
ArrayList<Integer> objectList = getObjectList();
Integer bestId = -1;
for(Integer currentObject : objectList) {
    if(currentObject > bestId) {
        bestId = currentObject;
    }
}
Iterator<Integer> iter = objectList.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    if(iter.next() != bestId) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Java Streams to solve this:

```
Collection<ObjectVO> result = objectList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ObjectVO::getID, Function.identity(),
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(ObjectVO::getVersion))))
        .values();
```

This creates a map which contains the max version for each id. Then you can just use `Map.values()` to get the object list.

If you need a `List` or an `ArrayList` you can just use `new ArrayList<>(result)`.